# Getting errors compiling ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, cygwin

I am compiling ffmpeg for android in windows with cygwin.

I am using-

1. android ndk r5
2. ffmpeg-0.10.3
3. cygwin

### Everything works fine but when i run last command then after few minutes it gives this error-

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later

Creating config.mak and config.h...

libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged

> WARNING:
> C:/android-ndk-r5-windows/android-ndk-r5//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config
> not found, library detection may fail.
>
> WARNING: Compiler does not indicate floating-point ABI, guessing soft.
>
> config.log:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
>
> config.log:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
>
> C:\android-ndk-r5-windows\android-ndk-r5\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe:
> cannot open output file ./android/armv7-a/libffmpeg.so: No such file
> or directory

please help me out to overcome this problem.

thanks.